# Taylor Series Proof for $(1−x+x^2)e^x$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I came across the following problem and have no idea where to start.  Here it is:

Prove that every nonzero coefficient of $(1−x+x^2)\text{e}^x$ is a rational number with a numerator of either 1 or a prime.

How does one solve this?

Comment: No, it isn't${}$.

Comment: @WilliamGrannis: Are you sure you wrote the problem correctly? If we write the Taylor series for the stated problem, we have $$1+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{2 x^3}{3}+\frac{3 x^4}{8}+\frac{2 x^5}{15}+\frac{5 x^6}{144}+\frac{x^7}{140}+\frac{7 x^8}{5760}+O\left(x^9\right)$$ How does that satisfy your statement regarding that every nonzero coefficient is either $1$ or a prime?

Comment: Can you copy the problem exactly as it appears?  As stated here, it doesn't really make sense (the coefficients aren't even integers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that the correct question is asking that the numerator of the coefficient of every power greater than $1$ of $x$ in the Taylor series is $1$ or a prime.  For $n \gt 1$ the coefficient of $x^n$ of our Taylor series is $$\frac 1{n!}-\frac 1{(n-1)!}+\frac 1{(n-2)!}=\frac {1-n+n(n-1)}{n!}=\frac{n^2-2n+1}{n!}=\frac {(n-1)^2}{n!}$$
If $n-1$ is prime, one factor will cancel with the $n-1$ in the denominator, leaving the numerator $n-1$, which is prime.  If $n-1$ is composite and not a square, factor it as $ab$.  Then $a,b,n-1$ are different numbers less than $n$ and all will cancel, leaving the numerator $1$.  If $n-1$ is a square $ p^2$ greater than $4$, the term is $\frac {p^4}{n!}$ and the terms $p,2p,p^2$ are all different numbers less than $n$ and the numerator will be $1$.  Now we check up to $n=5$, find the numerators are all $1$ or prime and we are done.

Comment: How did you get the expression for the series?

Comment: @WilliamGrannis:  just by adding the Taylor series together.  The one for $e^x$ is $\frac {x^n}{n!}$, for $xe^x$ is then $\frac {x^{n+1}}{n!}$ or by shifting $\frac {x^n}{(n-1)!}$ and similarly for $x^2e^x$

Comment: Thank you.  This really cleared things up for me.